# fragment to fragment animation with shared element don't work as expected

Tags: androidx, fragment-transitions

In an `AppCompatActivity` with a `RecyclerView` in a fragment (`myFragment1`), `viewholders` and so on, so if I click on an item, then `myFragment2` will show and display the detail of the item. In this phase, I want to create an animation between  the two fragments with shared elements.

Steps to reproduce the behaviour:

```
import android.view.View;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;
[...]
public class AppActivity extends AppCompatActivity

myFragment1.setSharedElementReturnTransition(new MyNewTransition());
myFragment1.setSharedElementEnterTransition(new MyNewTransition());
[...]
a) getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .addSharedElement(myImage, "mytransition")
                    .replace(R.id.recycler_view_container, myFragment2)
                    .commit();

b) getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .addSharedElement(myImage, "mytransition")
                    .add(R.id.recycler_view_container, myFragment2)
                    .hide(myFragment1) 
                     commit();
```

In the (a) code, the image transition is correct and animation occurs perfectly between the shared elements, but I don't need this.
In the (b) code, the only difference is that `myFragment1` is being hidden and the `myFragment2` is added, in this case both the enter transition and the return transition are broken and no animation occurs.

I need the (b) code because "replace"-ing the fragments will destroy the `myFragment1` and rebuilding it is a heavy-load process.
I think this is a bug with androidx libraries

**EDIT:**
I have build a sample based on the demonstration of Bryan Herbst:
[FragmentTransitionSample](https://github.com/bherbst/FragmentTransitionSample) and re-adapted for androidx, [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sIF6iXqndZTWLtRmL29q2Mil7-UHWmfb/view?usp=sharing) are the sources.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding `setReorderingAllowed(true)`

For example:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction() 
                .setReorderingAllowed(true)
                .addSharedElement(myImage, "mytransition") 
                .add(R.id.recycler_view_container, myFragment2) 
                .hide(myFragment1)  
                 commit();
```

Comment: No Daniel. There is flickering, and returning back with the back button, the fragment with kittens disappeared. All messed up.

Comment: i've had the same bug after migration to androidx and setReorderingAllowed(true) has fixed this.